# ld: framework not found KNSemiModalViewController clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, swift2, cocoapods, xcode7

I recently migrated to swift 2 and Xcode 7 and I got this error

```
Ld /Users/vitee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vitee-annteycycxyzpidgtqyojbrfeevj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Vitee.app/Vitee normal arm64
    cd "/Users/vitee/Desktop/Vitee-ios Normal2 7"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.3
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/vitee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vitee-annteycycxyzpidgtqyojbrfeevj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/vitee/Desktop/Vitee-ios\ Normal2\ 7/Pods/Google/Libraries -L/Users/vitee/Desktop/Vitee-ios\ Normal2\ 7/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries -L/Users/vitee/Desktop/Vitee-ios\ Normal2\ 7/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/vitee/Desktop/Vitee-ios\ Normal2\ 7/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/vitee/Desktop/Vitee-ios\ Normal2\ 7/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries -F/Users/vitee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vitee-annteycycxyzpidgtqyojbrfeevj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/vitee/Desktop/Vitee-ios\ Normal2\ 7/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks -F/Users/vitee/Desktop/Vitee-ios\ Normal2\ 7 -filelist /Users/vitee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vitee-annteycycxyzpidgtqyojbrfeevj/Build/Intermediates/Vitee.build/Debug-iphoneos/Vitee.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Vitee.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.3 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode-marker -ObjC -ObjC -lGGLAnalytics -lGGLCore -lGSDK_Overload -lGTMSessionFetcher_core -lGTMSessionFetcher_full -lGTMStackTrace -lGTM_AddressBook -lGTM_DebugUtils -lGTM_GTMURLBuilder -lGTM_KVO -lGTM_NSData+zlib -lGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments -lGTM_NSScannerJSON -lGTM_NSStringHTML -lGTM_NSStringXML -lGTM_Regex -lGTM_RoundedRectPath -lGTM_StringEncoding -lGTM_SystemVersion -lGTM_UIFont+LineHeight -lGTM_core -lGTM_iPhone -lGoogleAnalytics -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AFNetworking -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AddressBook -framework Alamofire -framework Bolts -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework GLKit -framework GoogleMaps -framework ImageIO -framework JLToast -framework KNSemiModalViewController_hons82 -framework Kingfisher -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SwiftValidator -framework SwiftyJSON -framework SystemConfiguration -framework THCalendarDatePicker -lc++ -licucore -lz -framework AFNetworking -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework Alamofire -framework Bolts -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework GLKit -framework GoogleMaps -framework ImageIO -framework KNSemiModalViewController -framework Kingfisher -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SwiftValidator -framework SwiftyJSON -framework SystemConfiguration -framework THCalendarDatePicker -ObjC -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/vitee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vitee-annteycycxyzpidgtqyojbrfeevj/Build/Intermediates/Vitee.build/Debug-iphoneos/Vitee.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Vitee.swiftmodule -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -weak_framework Pods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/vitee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vitee-annteycycxyzpidgtqyojbrfeevj/Build/Intermediates/Vitee.build/Debug-iphoneos/Vitee.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Vitee_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/vitee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vitee-annteycycxyzpidgtqyojbrfeevj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Vitee.app/Vitee

ld: framework not found KNSemiModalViewController
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The framework Search Paths is `- $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR) $(PROJECT_DIR)`
However when I remove the path, clean > build I then get no such module `FBSDKLoginKit`

The library Search Paths is `- $(inherited)`

I've been stuck on this for 3 days. Please help

Comment: where does your "`KNSemiModalViewController`" live?  somewhere inside your source code folder?

Comment: It lives in the pods folder

Comment: Hello anyone please help me

Comment: Add your static library from Edit Scheme-> Run if it is missed.